# keyboard-interactive authentication (Locked out?) on a Modern Honey Network Ubuntu 14.04 box?

Tags: command-line, ssh

I deployed a [Modern Honey Network](https://threatstream.github.io/mhn/) for a course project. I have a Ubuntu Box that hosts the MHN server and now I have deployed a Ubuntu 14.04 box to host several Sensors (Cowrie, Snort, etc.) However, after the testing of the ssh brute force, I can no longer login to my Ubuntu box.

Both putty and Linux terminal state that the Ubuntu Box is now `Using keyboard-interactive authentication` and even with the correct username and password, I am unable to login.

I have tried copy and passing the password in, typing it in manually, trying to login from different IP addresses, etc. I have no defenses in place as of yet (`fail2ban`, `denyhosts`, etc.). There is no SSH Key set-up, and I don’t want there to be. Just password authentication.

Here is the output of ssh -v:

```
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 57: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to ***SANITIZED*** [***SANITIZED***] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/josh/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/josh/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/josh/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/josh/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/josh/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/josh/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/josh/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/josh/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.8
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.0p1 
Debian-4+deb7u2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u2 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA ***SANITIZED***
debug1: Host '***SANITIZED***' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/josh/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: password,publickey,keyboard-
interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/josh/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/josh/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/josh/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/josh/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
Password:
debug1: Authentications that can continue: password,publickey,keyboard-
interactive
Password:
```

As requested - sshd_config file:

```
josh@ubuntu-HP:~$ sudo cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config
# Package generated configuration file
# See the sshd_config(5) manpage for details

# What ports, IPs and protocols we listen for
Port 2222
# Use these options to restrict which interfaces/protocols sshd will bind to
#ListenAddress ::
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
Protocol 2
# HostKeys for protocol version 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
#Privilege Separation is turned on for security
UsePrivilegeSeparation yes

# Lifetime and size of ephemeral version 1 server key
KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
ServerKeyBits 1024

# Logging
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:
LoginGraceTime 120
PermitRootLogin no
StrictModes yes

#RSAAuthentication yes
#PubkeyAuthentication yes
#AuthorizedKeysFile     %h/.ssh/authorized_keys

# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
IgnoreRhosts yes
# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh_known_hosts
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
# similar for protocol version 2
HostbasedAuthentication no
# Uncomment if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for RhostsRSAAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts yes

# To enable empty passwords, change to yes (NOT RECOMMENDED)
PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Change to no to disable tunnelled clear text passwords
#PasswordAuthentication yes

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosGetAFSToken no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes

# GSSAPI options
GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes

X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog yes
TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no

#MaxStartups 10:30:60
#Banner /etc/issue.net

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin yes
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes

# Added by DigitalOcean build process
ClientAliveInterval 120
ClientAliveCountMax 2

PasswordAuthentication yes
```

Comment: Please, post the content of your `sshd_config` file, maybe something there will make sense. However, few weeks ago I was reading about similar issue, and I'm almost sure the solution was reinstallation of SSH server, but I can't find this topic.

Comment: @SpasSpasov This has happened to me before, actaully quite often when testing brute force techniques and I have never been able to recover a box after this has happened..... But, above is the config file requested.